# Oracle - How to query when the date greater 3999.12.31?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to query when the date greater than 3999.12.31?
In the database are dates, greater than '3999.12.31'. Those values are not appear in SELECT statement.

Please help me

Éva

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. The quality of the answers is very much dependent on the quality of the question.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean? No problems here (Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production  ):

```
create table testdate (d date);

insert into testdate values (to_date('21-01-5001','DD-MM-YYYY'));

select * from testdate where d > to_date('31-12-3999','DD-MM-YYYY');

D                 
-------------------
21-01-5001 00:00:00
```

Comment: sorry, it is not work...

Comment: @user3652065 What is not work? We do not have a crystal ball. In order to help you we need more information then this.

Comment: @user3652065 What tools are you using to run the queries?  It may be an issue with the IDE, language, or library you are using.